# Clear mark attribute of a node in extract-min operation of Fibonacci Heap

Tags: heap, fibonacci-heap

In the `DECREASE-KEY` operation of Fibonacci Heap, whenever a node is cut from its parent and added to the root list, its mark attribute is set to `FALSE`. However, in the `EXTRACT-MIN` operation, the children of the min-node are added to the root list but their mark attributes aren't set to `FALSE`. Why is there such inconsistency?

Moreover, in the linking operation where a node is made the child of another node, the mark attribute of the new child is set to `FALSE`. The `EXTRACT-MIN` operation performs this linking operation multiple times. But in the amortized analysis of `EXTRACT-MIN` operation described in the CLRS book, the authors claim that the number of marked nodes doesn't change in `EXTRACT-MIN` operation. They use `m(H)` to denote the number of marked nodes both before and after `EXTRACT-MIN` operation. I am quoting the exact line from the book:

> The potential before extracting the minimum node is t(H)+2m(H), and
> the potential afterward is at most (D(n)+1)+2m(H).

Here `D(n)` is the maximum degree of any node in an n-node Fibonacci Heap, `t(H)` is the number of trees in the Fibonacci Heap and `m(H)` is the number of marked nodes in the Fibonacci Heap.

Isn't this calculation wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a step back - why do we need mark bits in a Fibonacci heap in the first place?

The idea behind a Fibonacci heap is to make the DECREASE-KEY operation as fast as possible. To that end, the basic strategy of DECREASE-KEY is to take the element whose key is being decreased and to cut it from its parent if the heap property is violated. Unfortunately, if we do that, then we lose the exponential connection between the order of a tree and the number of nodes in the tree. That's a problem because the COALESCE step of an EXTRACT-MIN operation links trees based on their orders and assumes that each tree's order says something about how many nodes it contains. With that connection broken, all the nice runtime bounds we want go away.

As a compromise, we introduce mark bits. If a node loses a child, it gets marked to indicate "something was lost here." Once a marked node loses a second child, then it gets cut from its parent. Over time, if you do a huge number of cuts in a single tree, eventually the cuts propagate up to root of the tree, decreasing the tree order. That makes the tree behave differently during a COALESCE step.

With that said, the important detail here is that ***mark bits are only relevant for non-root nodes.*** If a node is a root of a tree and it loses a child, this immediately changes its order in a way that COALESCE will notice. Therefore, you can essentially ignore the mark bit of any tree root, since it never comes up. It's probably a wise idea to clear a node's mark bit before moving it up to the root list just so you don't have to clear it later, but that's more of an implementation detail than anything else.